# Is one vector expressible as a linear combination of the columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the matrix A and vector b:

$$
    A = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & -1 & -3 \\
    6 & 1 & 4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
    b = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is **b** expressable as a linear combination of the columns of **A**?

I found the inverse of A to be $\begin{bmatrix}\frac 12 & \frac 12 & 0 \\9 & 5 & 3 \\-3 & -2 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$

I'm guessing that I have to multiply the inverse of **A** with the vector **b**, but I don't quite understand why. I'd get a $3 \times 1$, which would be useful as the coefficients of the columns of **A**. Once again though, I don't understand why this process works.

Can someone explain the logic of how this works? Also, can you tell early on if it's possible to even express this correctly?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible (which I guess it is if you found its inverse), then $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.  But you wanted to actually find a linear combination of the columns that gives $b$, you'd multiply $A^{-1}b$ and that column matrix would have the coefficients of your linear combo.

Comment: I guess my question is why that is the case then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ iff

$$\pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\ 3} = x\pmatrix{2 \\ 0 \\ 6} + y\pmatrix{1 \\ -1 \\ 1} + z\pmatrix{3 \\ -3 \\ 4} = \pmatrix{2 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & -1 & -3 \\ 6 & 1 & 4}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}$$

So since you found the inverse of $A$, you can multiply by it to get

$$A^{-1}b = A^{-1}AX = IX = X$$

which gives you the coefficients of your linear combination.

---

Note that if all you needed to know was *whether* $b$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$, you don't actually have to calculate the matrix $X$.  It's enough to know that $A$ is invertible because then you could see that $A^{-1}b = X$ would be a solution to the system.  So, because $A$ is square, you could just check whether or not its determinant is zero.  That would be a bit faster, but it wouldn't give you any info about *how* to write $b$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Writing out the actual algebra behind it clarified quite a bit. So $x, y, z$ would correspond to the vector you get from $A^{-1}b?$

Comment: Yep.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Have to try and remember there's intuitive algebra behind all of these operations. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. :-)